# Remove duplicated results using inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to see TotalSale values ONLY on the first row of TotalSale that matches with PricesTable DocNumber and DocType

```
SalesTable
ProductID  DocType  DocNumber  UnitPrice 
01         A        000001        150.00
05         A        000001        200.00
06         A        000001         80.00
65         C        002550      15000.00
30         B        002551        100.00
```

and

```
PricesTable
DocType  DocNumber  TotalSale
A        000001       430.00
C        002550     15000.00
B        002551       100.00
```

What I want to get is something like this

```
TotalSalesTable
ProductID  DocType  DocNumber  UnitPrice  TotalSale
01         A        000001        150.00     430.00
05         A        000001        200.00
06         A        000001         80.00
65         C        002550      15000.00   15000.00
30         B        002551        100.00     100.00
```

but instead I keep getting this:

```
TotalSalesTable
ProductID  DocType  DocNumber  UnitPrice  TotalSale
01         A        000001        150.00     430.00--> Good Value
05         A        000001        200.00     430.00--> This
06         A        000001         80.00     430.00--> and this are duplicated
65         C        002550      15000.00   15000.00
30         B        002551        100.00     100.00
```

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT ST.ProductID
    ,ST.DocType
    ,ST.DocNumber
    ,ST.UnitPrice
    ,PT.TotalSale
from SalesTable ST
INNER JOIN PricesTable PT
    on (ST.DocNumber=PT.DocNumber)
```

Comment: Those are the only columns we have for PricesTable, if i wanna get a custom report for the total sales i'll end up getting those duplicated values inside the report

Comment: Why to store the `TotalSale` in a separate table while you can calculate them from SalesTable?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i wanna do, but is it possible to get this by a simple query in Management Studio?

Comment: @Ahmed i honestly don't know who made it like that in first place, and yeah, i don't understand either, but its the way its made.

Comment: Yes, `SUM(UnitPrice) Over (Partition By DocType, DocNumber)`

Comment: I think it was the logic i was using, by summing those values, you wont get the right totalsales at the end of the query, sorry if i wasn't clear enough @DaleK, and thanks ahmed that was exactly the kind of answer i was trying to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try enumerating all the rows, then assign totalsales value only to those rows that are first for every docnumber:

```
 SELECT ST.ProductID
    ,ST.DocType
    ,ST.DocNumber
    ,ST.UnitPrice
    ,case when row_number() over 
    (partition by st.docnumber order by st.productid) = 1 
         then PT.TotalSale end as TotalSale
from SalesTable ST
INNER JOIN PricesTable PT
    on (ST.DocNumber=PT.DocNumber)
```

Edit: I would also recommend having two columns: one with a duplicated values for every docnumber, and another one with those values hidden except the first one. So that in future you can calculate ratios and aggregates from the output more comfortably.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required results without the need of the second table (PricesTable),

```
Select ProductID, DocType, DocNumber, UnitPrice,
       Case When ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By DocType, DocNumber Order By ProductID) = 1
            Then SUM(UnitPrice) Over (Partition By DocType, DocNumber) 
            Else ''
       End as TotalSale
From SalesTable
```

See a demo from [*db<>fiddle.*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6288518968029b105daa5a045e4d5ced)

Comment: This is actually useful, i'll get it in mind, thanks!